# Configuring Akamai to separately cache next gen images

Tags: cdn, akamai, imgix-js

We use a service, Imgix, that serves images in the most appropriate format for the client that requests them. So, if the request for a JPG comes from Chrome, it will send a WEBP image. If, it's from Safari, it will use JPEG2000.

We also use Akamai as CDN, so Akamai sits between users and Imgix.

If the first request for an image is from Chrome, Akamai will cache the WEBP format, and any future requests for the same image will receive a WEBP image, that means Safari users won't be able to view that image, because it's not compatible with the WEBP format.

Is it possible to configure AKAMAI to cache different images based on the format?

Comment: Akamai provide this image optimization (also image transformation). You may take a look at Image Manager

Answer (score 0):

With Akamai, you can always set custom caching rules based on filename, path, file extension, or almost any other criteria you can think of. It's all handled as a Rule in your Property. Simply set the Match for what you want the caching rule applied to, and then set the Caching Behavior.